# Can you embed a try in a Python list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there anyway to do the equivalent of this?

```
my_list = [try: my_dict["some_key"] except KeyError: 0 for my_dict in my_list]
```

Since dictionaries throw KeyErrors I want to catch the error if the element in the list does not have a "some_key" property. I know I could create a defaultdict by importing collections and sidestepping the exception, but I want to know if this is possible with out of the box dictionaries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. You can put only `for` loops, `if`'s and `else`'s.

What you *can* do, though, is use [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which never throws a KeyError:

```
my_list = [my_dict.get("some_key", 0) for my_dict in my_list]
```

The second argument is the default value in case the key does not exist. If you don't specify a default, the default default is None.

Comment: Thanks I ended up using this

Comment: Would it be faster with an if argument to check if the key is in dict instead of trying all keys with get?

Comment: @Varlor Using the value if the key exists and 0 if not is exactly what `get` does. Doing it manually might not be noticeably slower, but I don't think it would be faster.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not do this directly in a list comprehension.  You must factor the try/except logic out into a separate function, and then call the function.

There is an easy alternative for the use case shown in your question, though, using `dict.get`:

```
my_list = [my_dict.get('some_key', 0) for my_dict in my_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers mentioned you can not use an try-except inside a list comprehension. But as a tricky approach you can use `collections.defaultdict()` and override the `__missing__` attribute in order to catch the exceptions. Here is an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Mydefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mydefaultdict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return defaultdict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            return self.__missing__(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        # Instead of printing you can catch your exceptions in any way you like
        print("{} doesn't exist".format(key))
        if self.default_factory:
            return self.default_factory()  # You can rturn whatever you want here
```

Demo:

```
d = Mydefaultdict(None, {4: 'b', 1: 'a'})
print([d[i] for i in [1, 2]])

2 doesn't exist
['a', None]
```

Comment: Or merely use `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: @zondo No! we just want to override the `__missing__` method. Using `int` as the default factory function won't give us the desire behavior.

Comment: The desired behavior is to get a 0 when the key doesn't exist. Adding the key may be undesired, though.